# ¿No ingresa a mi archivo .js al momento de cargar el sitio web?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Mi problema es que actualmente estoy tratando de llamar una funcion de tipo onclic a travez de un button, pero al momento de dar clic sobre el button en la consola del navegador me sale que no esta definida:

Erro que me sale:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: siguiente_promo is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.php:227)
```

Codigo del button:

```
  <button type="button"  name="next" class="next action-button" value="Siguiente" onclick="siguiente_promo(0);" >
  Siguiente &nbsp <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></button>
```

Me marca ese error porque al momento de que quiero leer el archivo .js  no se lee lo que esta adentro.

Codigo de linkeo:

```
<script src="vista/plugin/form/archivo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Codigo al inicio de el archivo .js:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "formulario de promotor" );
    alert("Entro");
    var correcto=0;
});
```

El document.ready no lo ejecute, por lo menos el de el archivo donde se encuentra la funcion, ya borre cookies de mis navegadores y lo probe en tres diferentes browsers. La direccion es correcta porque antes funcionaba

Comment: aparte del error que te manda, te marca algún error de la carga del archivo?

Comment: @JuankGlezz no no manda ningun error, de hecho tengo el document.ready en todos mis archivos .js, pero no entra a unos, incluyendo el que tiene la funcion

Comment: puedes colocar un fragmento de código mas completo de como esta escrito tu archivo js, y como lo cargas desde la vista

Comment: @JuankGlezz gracias, ya encontre el error.

Comment: veo que es un error Tipográfico te sugiero eliminar esta pregunta ya que no aporta nada a la comunidad, y la cual terminara cerrada y en un futuro podría ser eliminada, por usuarios con mayor reputación.

Comment: @JuankGlezz si  trate de eliminarla, pero me dice que tiene respuesta y que no se puede hacer dicha eliminacion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontre el error, fue un error de dedo, el problema es que tenia esta linea de codigo en archivo .js

```
mensajeValidacion("cmbEstado_promotor","iderror_form"3,);
```

Por lo cual si entraba a mi archivo .js pero al percatarse de que habia error de sintaxis este se salia descartando lo que habia leido de mi archivo.

Answer (score 0):

1. Primero Verifica que el `link` si tiene la ruta correcta

```
<script src="vista/plugin/form/archivo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

2. Este código.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
/// dentro código se utiliza cuando quieres que se ejecute algo, cuando se carge el DOM.
});
```

3. Fuera del el generarías tu función del `onclick()` quedaría así.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  /// dentro codigo que quieres que se ejecute automaticamentecuando se carge el DOM
});
function siguiente_promo(dato){
  // tu codigo que se ejecute en onclick() ejemplo:
  alert("onclick ejecutado correctamente");
}
```

Comment: de hecho esta estructurado de esa forma, solo que no me ejecuta el document.ready y por ende no entra a mi archivo.js donde se encuentra mi funcion y am si la ruta es correcta, de hecho dejo de funcionar de la nada.